# List<IFormFile> Converts to String[] not FileParameter[] (NSwag)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nswag

I am using NSwag to generate my calls to the server and

I have something like this

//in a controller

```
public void Save([FromBody] SaveTestDto save){
   //some stuff here
}
```

SaveTestDto

```
public class SaveTestDto 
{
   public List<IFormFile> MyProperty2 {get; set;}
}
```

it gets rendered into this

```
myProperty2?: string[] | undefied
```

if I do this

```
public void Save([FromBody] SaveTestDto save, List<IFormFile> test){
   //some stuff here
}
```

then the type is of **FileParameter**

Not sure what is going on.

Comment: If you read your own question without any background knowledge. Do you think anyone could answer it?

Answer (score 0):

To upload file using a model with IFormFile property, the parameter should be transferred from the form, instead of from the request body.

So try to use the `[FromForm]` attribute. Code like this:

```
    [HttpPost("save")]
    public IActionResult Save([FromForm] SaveTestDto save)
    {
        //some stuff here

        return Ok(save);
    }
```

[image]

Then the swagger UI like this:

[image]

Comment: the project is not using the swaggerUI interface it is using the NSwag to generate the contracts so the javascript only needs to pass in the parameters (the stubs are made to do the http calls and such). I tried to change it to FromForm though and now the contract stub parameter takes every single property as a parameter (so now I got to pass in like 15 parameters separately into the method).

When I used FromBody it was just one paramater I had to pass in.

Comment: @chobo2 Same here. I'm still looking for a fix to get both FileParameter and keep my object from being exploded into the endpoint call.  Did you come to a better solution?